# Sum of "last period" reputation is wrong when a post I downvoted is deleted

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

When our reputation changes, the title of reputation tab in our profile includes how many internet points we received or lost since we last viewed the reputation page.

During that same period, I had downvoted a post and then that post got deleted.
However, the total sum of the reputation change doesn't include the `+1` of the deleted post but only includes the `-1` of the downvote.

See the following screenshot which the shows that reputation change was `24` when it should be `25`.

[image: Reputation in profile page]

In the previous image, the downvote is on Dec 5, the post was deleted on Dec 6, and I opened the reputation tab in my profile on Dec 12. So I guess I waited about 5-6 days between the time the post was deleted and the time I opened the reputation tab in my profile.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  It's probably cached.  Either way, how long have you waited? It's not going to update until a recalc is done, probably.

Comment: I really like “internet points”, can we please always call rep so?

Comment: @Seth The downvote is on Dec 5, the post was deleted on Dec 6, and I opened the reputation tab in my profile just today, so I guess I waited about 5 days. I think it's a very minor bug, but I just thought I'd report it since it just shows some calculation errors.